# Can mongoengine run raw query in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

In pymongo,I can run raw query like this:

```
 conn = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://" + mongo_url)
 db = conn[db]
 db.authenticate(username,password)
 coll = db["coll_name"]
 coll.find(raw_query)
```

How can I do that in mongoengine without creating a Document class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongoengine.connect` returns a client so maybe you can do the same just replacing the first line with `conn = mongoengine.connect()`.

Comment: You are totally right~~~I get it in page https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/connection.py.